# The set of points whose distance to a set $E$ in $\mathbb R^n $ is zero, is the same set $E$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, metric-spaces

If a set $E$ is contained in $\mathbb R^n$ with the standard euclidean norm and if define another set $B$ as the points in $\mathbb R^n$ whose distance to the set $E$ is zero, is it true that $E=B$?

I think that is obvious if $E$ is a closed set, but the statement is valid if $E$ is an open set?

Thanks for any clue!

Comment: Think about the points on the boundary of the set $E.$

Comment: What happens with the open set $E=(0,1)$ contained in $\mathbb{R}$? What is $d(0,E)$?

Comment: Yes. It is the definition of distance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Let $n=1, E=\mathbb R\setminus \{0\}$(the real line minus the origin). ($E$ is open.)

The origin $0$ is not contained in $E$ but the distance from the origin to $E$ is zero. So $B=\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 1):

You have the follow B=$\bar{E}$